# SharePoint 2010 Foundation css url in Master Page

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, master-page

I have an image that is located at the root Style Library site. I want to put that image in the MasterPage. Using SharePoint Designer, I get this reference `background-image:url('../../../../Style Library/banner/Middle.png');`The link is working fine for the root site and its sub-sites. But as soon as I open a site in the sub-site, the image is not displaying anymore. I;m using SharePoint 2010 Foundation. how do I fix this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the users has access to the root site, use the root relative site url. If the root site is located under the "slash" (like http://intranet/ or http://contoso.com), so you can refer to the image directly using slash in front of the url, called [root-relative url](http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/linking.php)

```
background-image:url('/Style Library/banner/Middle.png');
```

Comment: Thanks!, it worked. Could you please explain a bit more why it worked, I'm not that good with css.

Comment: It is not the matter of CSS (neither of SharePoint). You can use absolute urls (`'http://contoso/Style Library/banner/Middle.png'`), or relative (`'../../../Style Library/banner/Middle.png'`) or "root-relative": (`'/Style Library/banner/Middle.png'`). [See a simple intro these three url types](http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/linking.php)